# Overloading Equality and Comparison Operators with non Bool Return types

Tags: f#

Is there a specific reason why overriding the equality and comparison operators to produce a type other than bool is so difficult.

I have a workaround below, but why wouldn't the language make this easier to do?

What I am working with here is an external library which has these operators overloaded already, I simply want them to work the same way in F#.  It just doesn't seem right that I have to do this in order to accomplish that.

```
type ATArrayLT = ATArrayLT with
    static member        (?<-) (x:ATArray, ATArrayLT, y:int    ) = ATArray.op_LessThan(x, float32 y)
    static member        (?<-) (y:int    , ATArrayLT, x:ATArray) = ATArray.op_LessThan(x, float32 y)        
    static member        (?<-) (x:ATArray, ATArrayLT, y:float32) = ATArray.op_LessThan(x, y)
    static member        (?<-) (y:float32, ATArrayLT, x:ATArray) = ATArray.op_LessThan(x, y)
    static member        (?<-) (x:ATArray, ATArrayLT, y:ATArray) = ATArray.op_LessThan(x, y)
    static member inline (?<-) (x        , ATArrayLT, y        ) = x < y

let inline (<) x y = x ? (ATArrayLT) <- y
```

Answer (score 1):

The comparison and equality operators (`<`, `>`, `=`) have well-defined behavior ([spec §8.15.6](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc335818970)). Specifically, comparison depends on an `IComparable` implementation and equality depends on `Equals`.

There is only a passing resemblance to the operators of the same name in C#. You can still provide the C# variants, complete with non-traditional behavior, to be used from other .NET languages

```
type T() =
  static member op_LessThan (a: T, b: T) = new obj()
```

but they have no effect on F#'s equality and comparison operators.

Comment: Comparison and equality aren't structural for all types in F# -- only tuples and "lists, options, arrays, and user-defined record, union, and struct types whose constituent field types permit structural equality, hashing, and comparison". So for a user-defined class it *should* be OK to overload those operators.

Comment: That's true. My point was that equality/comparison have different, and well-defined, behavior in F#. They're not syntactic sugar with ad-hoc meanings as they are in C#. They _can_ be customized in F#, just not to the extent the OP wants.

Comment: Is there any risk in using the above approach?